# Existence of linear disjointness between an algebraic number field and $p$-cyclotomic field over $ \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, number-fields, cyclotomic-fields

Suppose $ K $ be an algebraic number field and $ n $ be an even integer. Is it possible to find atleast one $ p $ such that $ p\equiv 1( \text{mod}~ n)$ and $ \mathbb{Q}(\eta_p) $ is linearly disjoint to $ K(\eta_4) $ where $ \mathbb{Q}(\eta_p)$ denotes the smallest field containing $ \mathbb{Q}$ and primitive $p$-th root of unity $\eta_p$ and $ \eta_4$ be primitive $ 4 $-th root of unity.

Comment: You could've equivalently assumed $\eta_4\subset K$ in the beginning so you don't have to adjoin it later.

Answer (score 3):

Assume without loss that $K/\mathbb Q$ is Galois and contains $\eta_4$. Then it suffices to check there exists a prime $p\equiv1\pmod n$ such that $\mathbb Q(\eta_p)\cap K=\mathbb Q$. Now the maximal abelian sub-extension of $K$, $K^{ab}/\mathbb Q$ is included in some $\mathbb Q(\eta_N)$ for some $N$ by the Kronecker-Weber theorem, and so $\mathbb Q(\eta_p)\cap K= \mathbb Q(\eta_p)\cap K^{ab}\subset \mathbb Q(\eta_p)\cap\mathbb Q(\eta_N)$. So taking $p\nmid N$ is enough.

Comment: how linearly disjointness follows from $\mathbb Q(\eta_p)\cap K=\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Because by Galois theory $[\mathbb Q(\eta_p)K:K]=[\mathbb Q(\eta_p):\mathbb Q(\eta_p)\cap K]=[\mathbb Q(\eta_p):\mathbb Q]$, so $[\mathbb Q(\eta_p)K:\mathbb Q]=[\mathbb Q(\eta_p):\mathbb Q][K:\mathbb Q]$.